# PHP Notice: Undefined variable in PHP

Tags: php, smarty

Can someone help me out as i'm new to PHP.

I'm using smarty template engine and what i'm trying to do is on my site each movie has it's own category and i'm trying to display the category underneath the movie by using this function.

```
/* returns a list of categories (including ids and details) for the given movie */

public function getMovieCategoryDetails($movieid,$lang=null){
    $movieid = mysql_real_escape_string($movieid);
    $e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movie_tags WHERE id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM movie_tags_join WHERE movie_id=$movieid)") or die(mysql_error());
    $tags = array();
    if (mysql_num_rows($e)){
        while($s = mysql_fetch_array($e)){
            $s['tag'] = json_decode($s['tag'],true);
            if ($lang){
                $s['tag'] = $s['tag'][$lang];
            }

            $tags[$s['id']] = $s;
        }
    }
    return $tags;
}
```

And then this to call the function.

```
$tags = $movie->getMovieCategoryDetails($movieid,$language);
if (count($tags)){
    $smarty->assign("tags",$tags);
}
```

And then this to display it.

```
{if $movie_tags}
<tr>
    <td width="70"><strong>Tags:</strong></td>
    <td style="width:387px; float:left;">
        <span class="movie_info">
        {foreach from=$movie_tags key=tag_id item=tag name=tags}
            {$tags}
        {/foreach}  
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
{/if}
```

But get this error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

And in the PHP_ERROR_LOG i got this error.

```
[11-Oct-2013 11:18:16 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: movieid in C:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 69
```

Can anyone please point me in the direction on solving this error.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the error message provides ample information for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the php error points to the same problem as the MySQL-error:

It seems your variable `$movieid` is not initialized, therefore the SQL-statement fails and throws an error at the last bracket.

Maybe you can ensure that by putting some debug outputs before the SQL-statement is being built `$e = ....` to see what is inside that variable and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a `echo $movieid;` before this line:

```
$tags = $movie->getMovieCategoryDetails($movieid,$language);
```

Just to be sure, if the function is recieving a correct id.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a STRICT environment for your development (and you should) and PHP 5.5 or greater mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated. Therefor their could be an error being returned by it. Is there a error previous to the one you mentionned in your Apache log ?